# How can I restore my partition with data

Tags: diskpart

While installing Windows 10 from the Repair Tools command prompt, I ran clean command by mistake on the whole disk, so it becomes a single 465GB partition. Previously, it contained four partitions.

How can I recover them with the data intact? I used list partition but is not going show me any dara

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1001110/how-to-recover-data-and-partition-after-diskpart-clean?rq=1 and https://superuser.com/questions/906184/undo-diskpart-clean?rq=1 and https://superuser.com/questions/949510/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-recover-an-ntfs-partition?rq=1

Comment: @user1686 - Questions are expected to be well researched.  So while answers indicating you should "do a google search" are not welcome at Super User, questions seeking a catch-all solution are also quickly closed as being "too broad".  You have not indicated what you have tried if anything, other then listing partitions, which isn't really trying anything because you indicated you specifically deleted the partitions.  As there are no less than 5 potential duplicates to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm here to tell you that if you used diskpart's "clean all" command, you won't be getting that data back. Clean all completely zero's all bits on the drive making anything unrecoverable.

Standard diskpart clean is equivalent to a format. Still not going to be easy to get your stuff back, but it is possible in theory.

For example, EaseUS data recovery software claims to be able to do this, though I have not tested it myself.

Answer (score 0):

As boog answered its hard to recover data after zero fill but still I believe nothing is impossible in this world and its better to give a try before saying impossible

In this technological advancement world daily new advanced softwares and apps are coming may be one can work. No one can tell you have to give a try to test which of them work and get your data back. There are many recovery software which claims that can recover  after disk part cleanup. I have not tried used but  Some of them I searched for you and you can try and test it in your case

Some of them I  have linked videos and links which can help you

1. Undo  diskpart cleanup

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=3SdL-XgskOg

2. MiniTool Power Data Recovery Free Edition V7.0

[Recover Data Lost By DiskPart Clean – Complete Guide - MiniTool](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.minitool.com/amp/data-recovery/recover-data-lost-by-diskpart-clean.html&ved=2ahUKEwiwqPCK9f_nAhXKZSsKHVMBA1cQFjAQegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1Ca7k258-uqHMfDHLwOtoX&ampcf=1&cshid=1583294666082)

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9GuNxeTY_1I

3. EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard

[Completely Recover Data Lost by DISKPART Clean/Format - EaseUS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.easeus.com/data-recovery-solution/recover-data-lost-by-diskpart-format-clean.html&ved=2ahUKEwiwqPCK9f_nAhXKZSsKHVMBA1cQFjACegQIChAN&usg=AOvVaw2DDTbF8Szj1FiPcDZUpHbf&cshid=1583294666082)

4. TestDisk
5. AOMEI Partition Assistant Professional.

https://www.diskpart.com/articles/how-to-recover-data-lost-by-diskpart-clean-0310.amp.html

6. Runtime GetMyDataBack

Be careful to follow steps and don't delete or clean up again or zero fill. I have given some tolls if they dont work then fans more and try if don't work hire a company service which can recover it for you if data is precious some professionals can program and get out data to

Comment: Thanx a lot bro

Comment: @Ti Simon bro did u tried any  of the method did u got ur partition data back which method software worked